# Task scheduler PowerShell Start-Process is not running

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, start-process

I have this simple script on Windows 10, which works fine when just executing, but fails to start notepad when running from task scheduler. **Stop-Process works perfectly, Start-Process does not run.** When I run it on demand, it closes the notepad and then keeps running without opening notepad, the task does not close also.

```
Stop-Process -processname notepad
Start-Process "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

This is how it is configured to run.
[image]
[image]
Things I have tried, but still does not work.

1. First of all, I am running under administrator account.
2. In task schduler, run with highest privileges is checked.
3. I have tried `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
4. Under security policy have given my user `Logon as batch` job permission
5. Turn UAC off

Comment: The task scheduler runs as a background service so you won't have a GUI but you should see notepad.exe in the task manager - do you?

Comment: Ah I did not know that it runs it as background service, yeah I see it in task manager. Any way to actually run it as normal application?

Comment: I doubt its possible. I just added it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for comments, this led me to new path and got it solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application was ran in background. To make it run on foreground, had to check the box **Run only when user is logged on**.

[image]

Comment: Didn't knew that this is possible at all. Nice.